# open document with office365 using ASP.NET C# web application

Tags: asp.net, office365

I've been developing a web application with asp.net webforms and in this app I have some documents (.doc, .docx, .rtf files), and my client want to open/edit these files on browser using office 365, they want to open a document in Office365, edit, save it on server (without downloading) and close it. I know it's difficult but I would like to know if it's possible or if is there any easy way to do it. How can i integrate office 365 with my asp.net application?

Answer (score 0):

use shift + right click on the file, you will find and option "open with" in context menu. Go to "choose default program" and choose Office365 location. There should be an checkbox to remember using this program for these file types.  dont forget to check that.